# How to prevent login window from displaying in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, shiro

I have a nav bar and ng-view in the index.html,when session time out, the login window will display in the ng-view, so there will be a nav bar and log in form in the same page. I want to just display the log in window, anyone could help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about ng-show?

Comment: Actually I used both angularJs and Shiro at the same time, when session time out, I want the page totally jump to login.jsp, so that I can log again. But now the login window displayed with nav bar at the same page, and I could not log in the system by specifying the correct username/password, I don't know why, and I don't know either angularJs or shiro make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in scope named loggedIn that will be true when logged in, and when your user logs out will be false.

Then use these tags in your HTML.

```
<...navbar element data-ng-show='loggedIn'>
<...log in form data-ng-hide='loggedIn'>
```

Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/99gqku83e1g2jRfUdXTp?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ngShow:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Just use it on the top-most navbar element with an expression such that it only shows when the session has not timed out.